# Get Canvas in LWUIT app

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, series-40, nokia-s40

I tried set `fullScreenMode(false)` for my app (LWUIT). But can not get Canvas.

1 way: `com.nokia.mid.ui.LCDUIUtil.setObjectTrait(javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent(), "nokia.ui.canvas.status_zone", Boolean.FALSE);`

2 way: `javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent().setFullScreenMode(false);`

But I have error. Method getCurrent() return class Displayable which don't have method `setFullScreenMode()`.

Also I tried `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas)javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(this).getCurrent()` but it return null.

What is way for resolved this problem?

Comment: I had to apply a wait for about 5 seconds for the last way not to throw a null pointer error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last way is correct, you need to use it AFTER invoking `form.show()` for it to actually work.